Swift Global Variable Changing Unintentionally with Another Variable
I have two variables declared in a file called Globals. This file contains no classes, just global variables and functions. I initially set each variable to be an empty list of Players, a class I created in a separate file called Classes.
var repPlayers: [Player] = []

var oldRepPlayers: [Player] = []

class Reporter: Codable {
    var name = "Unset"
    var valid = false
    
    init(name: String, valid: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.valid = valid
    }
}

extension Reporter: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Reporter, rhs: Reporter) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.valid == rhs.valid
    }
}

class Player: Codable {
    var pName = "Unset"
    var reps = 0
    var repts: [Reporter] = []
    var defState = "None"
    var state = "None"
    
    init(pName: String, reps: Int, repts: [Reporter], defState: String, state: String) {
        self.pName = pName
        self.reps = reps
        self.repts = repts
        self.defState = defState
        self.state = state
    }
}

extension Player: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Player, rhs: Player) -> Bool {
        return lhs.pName == rhs.pName && lhs.reps == rhs.reps && lhs.repts == rhs.repts && lhs.defState == rhs.defState && lhs.state == rhs.state
    }
}

Once my app launches, an API request is processed and it sets both variables to a parsed version of the JSON data returned. Once the user switches to a separate tab in a tab bar controller, a Timer.scheduledTimer is activated every ten seconds to check the API for changes and upload new data. The problem arises when checking the API to see if it updated from input from a separate client. This is where the two variables come in. One is called oldRepPlayers, while the other is called repPlayers. The checking function is in the Globals file, and it first retrieves the data from the API and puts it into a variable called listOfPlayers, after it sterilizes it to a list of Players. Next, it uses this code to test if any of the Players in the list changed.
if listOfPlayers != oldRepPlayers {
    print(listOfPlayers[3].state)
    for (index, player) in listOfPlayers.enumerated() {
        if player != oldRepPlayers[index] {
            repPlayers[index] = player
        }
    }
    oldRepPlayers = listOfPlayers
}

The problem is that if I change the repPlayers variable before this function is called, but not the API or the oldRepPlayers variable, it resets the repPlayers variable back to what it was before, which is the new listOfPlayers variable.
I did some testing and debugging, and found that the oldRepPlayers variable changed when I preformed a leadingEdgeSwipeAction for a cell in a table that held the data. When the action was preformed it ran the following code:
if repPlayers[indexPath.row].state == "Exempt" {
    repPlayers[indexPath.row].state = ""
} else {
    repPlayers[indexPath.row].state = "Exempt"
}

It was here where the oldRepPlayers variable changed, according to the debugger, even though I didn't even use it's name. This also occurred when I used a trailingEdgeSwipeAction.
Here is a GitHub Repository of the XCode project. I switched out my X-Master-Key for a different value, to keep the original private, however, the API requests succeeded with the correct key.

You are aware that when you work with classes then you change all references to an instance when you change that instance? So if the same player object exists in both arrays then both arrays will be updated. The normal and recommended way is to use struct for model types like Player

I also think the enumeration code looks really fragile since it so much depends on the sorting always being the same and it doesn’t handle removal of objects well as I see it.

@Josiah Schatz, "I switched out my X-Master-Key for a different value". Since you have provided GitHub link, I checked your commit and saw a key starting with $2a, is that your original key?, if yes give a new link without your key

@JoakimDanielson Is there any way you could tell me how to do that or provide me with a youtube tutorial or something? Also I'm not sure what you mean when you said that my enum code was fragile.

@Immanuel Yes that was my key sorry. Thanks for letting me know. I will reset it now.

@JoakimDanielson I think maybe I am beginning to understand what you are saying, are you saying that I should declare my Player class as a struct instead of a class?

@JoakimDanielson actually that worked thank you so much!

Thanks to @JoakimDanielson this question has been answered! For future viewers the problem was that I was using classes instead of structs.
